# Loop through Comments and Parse an xml using XMLTABLE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, xmltable

I need to parse an XML of the format below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
   <!-- ABSP65v9 -->
   <table border="1" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>eCQM Title</th>
            <th>Version specific identifier</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Controlling High Blood Pressure</td>
            <td>2c928085-7198-38ee-0171-9da6456007ab</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <list>
      <item>
         <content styleCode="Bold">Initial Population</content>
         :1000
         <list>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender - Male</content>
               400
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender -
                                        Female</content>
               600
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Ethnicity - Not Hispanic or
                                            Latino</content>
               350
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Ethnicity - Hispanic or
                                            Latino</content>
               650
            </item>
         </list>
      </item>
      <item>
         <content styleCode="Bold">Denominator Exclusions</content>
         :50
         <list>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender - Male</content>
               30
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender - Female</content>
               20
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Ethnicity - Not Hispanic or
                                            Latino</content>
               40
            </item>
         </list>
      </item>
   </list>
   <!-- KYCG138v9 -->
   <table border="1" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>eCQM Title</th>
            <th>Version specific identifier</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Preventive Care and Screening: Tobacco Use: Screening and
                                        Cessation Intervention</td>
            <td>2c928085-7198-38ee-0171-99aa63300462</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <list>
      <item>
         <content styleCode="Bold">Initial Population</content>
         :1000
         <list>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender - Male</content>
               400
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender -
                                        Female</content>
               600
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Ethnicity - Not Hispanic or
                                            Latino</content>
               350
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Ethnicity - Hispanic or
                                            Latino</content>
               650
            </item>
         </list>
      </item>
      <item>
         <content styleCode="Bold">Denominator Exclusions</content>
         :50
         <list>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender - Male</content>
               30
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Gender - Female</content>
               20
            </item>
            <item>
               <content styleCode="Bold">Ethnicity - Not Hispanic or
                                            Latino</content>
               40
            </item>
         </list>
      </item>
   </list>
</text>
```

The above XML has two comments `<!-- ABSP65v9 -->` and `<!-- KYCG138v9 -->` and each comment has nodes `<table>` and `<list>` respectively that have some content.

I want the output as below:

| Comment | table_xml_content | list xml |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABSP65v9 | `<table>content of table</table>` | `<list>content of list</list>` |
| KYCG138v9 | `<table>content of table</table>` | `<list>content of list</list>` |

Please let me know how this can be achieved using XMLTABLE function. I am using Postgres version 12.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
select x.table_comment,
       x.table_content,
       x.list_content
from the_table
  cross join xmltable('/text/table' passing data 
           columns table_content xml path '.',
                   table_comment text path 'normalize-space(preceding::comment()[1])',
                   list_content xml path 'following-sibling::list') as x
```

However, I am not 100% sure that matching the comment that way does work reliably.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=08419212205f4ea7f2eb3840f8f3d7b4)

Comment: Great! That worked indeed! Thank you so much!